Can I have multiple instances of TinyUSB configured as a USB device (VCP) on a single microcontroller?
I have a situation where I want to control 3 separate units from a single microcontroller. The units have USB ports configured as USB hosts, and expect a USB virtual COM port. Is this possible with TinyUSB? Potentially with a Raspberry Pi RP2040?

No, that's really unlikely to be possible, because you need special hardware in the silicon to implement processing of USB signals, especially if you are implementing USB on the device side.  I've never heard of a microcontroller with more than one USB module in it.
If possible, you'd want to reconfigure these units to act as USB devices, not hosts.  Or you could connect a USB-to-serial adapter to each one, and control them from the UARTs on our microcontroller.  The RP2040 has two UARTs and you can dynamically change which pins they are assigned to.
